# Dividing list elements and append them to a new list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list `V` which represents Velocity:

```
V = [1, 6, 8, 19, 19.5, 20, 21]
```

and I want to get a new list called `distance`. The distance is the old distance + `Velocity/3600` (To change from Km/h to Km/s). This is my code:

```
disntance = 0    
for k in range(len(V)):
    distance[k] = V[k]/3600 + distance[k-1]
```

and I'm getting an error message:

```
out of the index or I cant divide list to int
```

My expected output is:

```
distance = [0.000277, 0.00194, 0.0041667, 0.00944, 0.01486, 0.020416, 0.02625]
```

Comment: your variable distance is an int not a list. secondly you cannot assign to a key which is not available. use ```insert()``` if you dont want to ```append```

Comment: Do you want a faster way to do such calculations? It would also improve your structural code. If so, try reading about numpy arrays

Comment: Thanks for the tip,i got introduced to numpy after this question. Im just trying to improve my question right now.

Comment: @Ezzaldeen Alribi You should ask a new question if this one is already solved :)

Comment: This is answered, but the website asks me to imporve my previous questions and thats what im doing, so please if you see this question is clear and direct please upvote it

Comment: Please stop with the insignificant edits

Comment: Im tryin to find a way to enhance the Quality of the question, so the ban question can be lifted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed up `int` and `list` here.

If you want to track distance with a `list`:

```py
v = [1,6,8,19,19.5,20,21]
distance = [0];

for k in range(len(v)):
    distance.append(v[k]/3600 + distance[k])
    
distance
#[0, 0.0002777777777777778, 0.0019444444444444446, 0.004166666666666667,
# 0.009444444444444445, 0.014861111111111111, 
# 0.020416666666666666, 0.02625]
```

Or with an `int` only:

```py
v = [1,6,8,19,19.5,20,21]
distance = 0;

for k in range(len(v)):
    distance += v[k]/3600
    
distance
# 0.02625
```

Comment: if you find the question quality is improved, could you please upvote it?